# Работа с видео и изображением в делфи

Tags: delphi

1. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в делфи программно загрузить видео?
   То есть по нажатию на кнопку вызвать диалоговое окно и выбрать видео
   из имеющихся на компьютере.
2. как в делфи картинку с расширением `bmp` преобразовать в матрицу, элементами которой будут значения цветов каждого пикселя?

Answer (score 2):

Если с видео разобрались, то с загрузкой BMP и превращению его в матрицу ещё проще:

Располагаем на форме объект `TImage` (пусть будет Image1). Загружаем с помощью `TOpenDialog/TOpenPictureDialog` или руками посредством  `Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('имя_файла.bmp');` нужную картинку. Свойство `Image1.Canvas.Pixels` представляет собой ту самую матрицу цветов, которая вам нужна. Обращаясь `Image1.Canvas.Pixels[x,y]` вы получаете цвет в формате `TColor` (Фактически, RGBA формат).

Например:

```
var
  tc:TColor;

Image1.Picture.Create.LoadFromFile('c:\photos\flower01.bmp');
tc:=Image1.Canvas.Pixels[10,20]; // получаем цвет пикселя с координатами (10;20)
```

Данная матрица будет адресоваться с [0,0] до [Image1.Picture.Width-1,Image1.Picture.Height-1]. При выходе за границу изображения будет возвращаться -1.

Answer (score 0):

1. Куда загрузить? `OpenDialog` тоже поддерживает видео. Если нужно проигрывать на форме, то можно воспользоваться COM Windows Media Player.
2. Например, с помощью `GetPixel()`. Чтобы `GetPixel()` работала быстрее, можно использовать многопоточность.

Comment: я не особо в этом разбираюсь, но с GetPixel() я уже пробовал - не получилось. какие-нибудь наброски кода можете прислать?

Comment: можно без многопоточности, мне скорость не важна

Comment: с видео разобрался, спасибо